# android-n-preview-3 flash to nexus 6p

Tags: android, flash, daydream, nexus-6p

I download the android-n-preview-3 source code and copy android-msm-angler-3.10-n-preview-3 to kernel folder, build it and flash all the image to nexus 6p. but nexus 6p can not boot up.So what i have to do?

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a little more context.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to download the sources and build it yourself.
Download the [Official N Preview](https://developer.android.com/preview/download.html) image for the [Nexus 6P](http://storage.googleapis.com/androiddevelopers/shareables/preview/angler-npd35k-factory-81c341d5.tgz) and then [flash it](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images).

**To flash a system image:**

1. Download the appropriate system image for your device below, then unzip it to a safe directory.
2. Connect your device to your computer over USB.
3. Start the device in fastboot mode with one of the following methods:

   - Using the adb tool: With the device powered on, execute:
     `adb reboot bootloader`
   - Using a key combo: Turn the device off, then turn it on and immediately hold down the relevant [key combination](https://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html#booting-into-fastboot-mode) for your device. For example, to put a Nexus 6P ("angler") into fastboot mode, press and hold `Volume Down + Power` as the device begins booting up.
4. If necessary, unlock the device's bootloader by running:

`fastboot flashing unlock`

The target device will show you a confirmation screen. (This erases all data on the target device.)

5. Open a terminal and navigate to the unzipped system image directory.
6. Execute the `flash-all` script. This script installs the necessary bootloader, baseband firmware(s), and operating system.

Once the script finishes, your device reboots. You should now lock the bootloader for security:

1. Start the device in fastboot mode again, as described above.
2. Execute:
   `fastboot flashing lock`

Locking bootloader will wipe the data on some devices. After locking the bootloader, if you want to flash the device again, you must run `fastboot flashing unlock` again, which will wipe the data.